# Are the following two iptables rules equivalent?

Tags: linux, iptables, rate-limiting

There are articles such as [this](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/how-to-block-ssh-brute-force-attacks/) which suggest something of the form of these iptables rules to block too many SSH connections made in a short time:

```
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent  --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 -j DROP
```

According to the article, "[these rules] will block an IP if it attempts more than 3 new connections per minute to SSH."

If iptables' INPUT chain is configured to a default policy of DROP, will the following rule perform equivalently as the previously shown rules?

```
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: For those who look at the first two rules here, note that the second rule should be using `--rcheck`, otherwise, the `--set` and the `--update` do an update of the recent list and that means you get your counter incremented by 2 when the `--update` is "true" (i.e. once you have 4 hits, you get +2 each time a packet goes through.)

Answer (score 2):

The iptables module: `limit` and `recent` can be equivalent in some cases including the case you have at hand.

Here is a similar post on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/333480/58024).